# Does this WWII photo show a double-track railway?

Tags: world-war-two, photography, railroads, photograph

Recently I found a Bellingcat article titled [*Solving World War II Photo Mysteries With Open Source Techniques*](https://www.bellingcat.com/news/2023/08/04/solving-world-war-ii-photo-mysteries-with-open-source-techniques/). They close the article by saying:

> There are still many more images in the IBCC archives whose dates and
> locations are unknown. They can be found [here](https://ibccdigitalarchive.lincoln.ac.uk/omeka/mystery-items).

(IBCC stands for: [International Bomber Command Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bomber_Command_Centre).)

Following the Bellingcat-provided IBCC link, I found [the following group of images](https://ibccdigitalarchive.lincoln.ac.uk/omeka/collections/document/17644):

[image]

**My focus is on the top left one.** IBCC has the following to say about it:

> A target photograph showing open countryside. On the left is a line of
> bomb craters in fields. Roads are also visible here as is a railway
> line. On the right, the ground is obscured by smoke. The photograph is
> annotated '3B' but there is no caption to identify the target.

**I would like to find out what location the image shows.**

A promising line seems to be to look up where Axis-power railways existed at the time, and try to match the nearby roads. I believe it's likely roads haven't moved significantly since then. The description mentions a railway line. I zoom in to the part I believe to be the railway line:

[image]

First I thought the two dark lines are the two rails of a single railway line. Knowing that gauge distance is probably around 1.5m ([Wikipedia: *Standard-gauge railway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard-gauge_railway)), and that the two dark lines are around 4 pixels apart, I could conclude that pixel size on this image is less than ~40 cm.

If I zoom in to the roads, I can see that they are not wider than around 3 pixels. Having roads less than ~1.5m is not quite realistic.

This leads me to the belief that the two dark lines on the image are not the two rails of  a single railway, but a double-track railway.

If this was true, tracking down the location would become simpler, as I would only need to check the proximity of double-track railways, not every single railway.

### Does this WWII photo show a double-track railway?

Comment: Is this really a question about history? It does not seem to me to be about  Historical events, or Cultures and historical practices, or Famous people or Ancient Languages.